# How to submit the Place Order button onclick in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building custom payment plugin. When the user clicks the Place Order button, I have to pass the Billing Address information in JavScript function to the 3rd party JavaScript function and get the response in JavaScript, then process the payment. How to achieve this in WooCommerce custom payment plugin?

For example:

```
<iframe>
    <form></form>
</iframe>

//outside place order button
```

When the user clicks the Place Order button have to pass the script and get the response in script then process the payment like normal payment gateway plugin.

```
public function process_payment($order_id){
    echo '<script>
        alert("hi");
    </script>';        
}
```

The above code is not working.

Comment: If that code is "not working" (whatever that exactly means), what keeps you from writing other code?

Comment: What is best approach to pass the javscript event for place order button